# Why are ::before and ::after pseudo-elements detected but not shown in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to design a horizontal rule break that is a 1px line. In the middle of the line, there is an svg. So I'm using hr:before and hr:after for that:

```
<hr class="linha" />
```

SCSS:

```
hr.linha {
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid $primary;
    height: 0;
    margin: 4rem auto 4rem;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;

    &::before {
        content: "";
        background: white url("/img/logo-e.svg") no-repeat center;
        background-size: 20px 20px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
        top: -15px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    &::after {
        content: " ";
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

Firefox and Safari show it as expected: a horizontal like with an image in the middle. Chrome only shows an uninterrupted horizontal line. The ::before pseudo element is there, but nothing is visually printed on the screen.

On Chrome's Inspector, "computed styles" show that it's computing the image and the image can be seen, which means that the url path is correct.

What I have already tried:

- Using :before or ::before
- Using only :before
- Using content: url("logo.svg") instead of background: url("logo.svg")
- Using content: "some text" instead of background: url("logo.svg")
- Applying display: inline-block or display: block

Why does Chrome not show the :before pseudo element?

Comment: Did you already tried adding width and height?

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to mention that. Yes, I've tried setting width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if use position relative, chrome Taking auto width for before .if use position absolute, logo is displayed correctly.

```
hr.linha:before {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Positioning it becomes slightly more difficult, but Chrome now shows it. Thanks!

For future reference: when positioning objects, always check the computed styles. It was showing width set to auto, which I hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Mozilla Firefox browser, or

```css
hr.linha:before {
    position: absolute;
}
```